# spring-data-jdbc how to specify schema name

Tags: spring-data, jdbctemplate, querydsl

When using spring-data QueryDslJdbcTemplate to query, can I specify table schema name - different to the jdbc username in the datasource? Thanks.
(the generated qBean from querydsl-maven-plugin used the correct schema name, however, when I'm querying, the template always use jdbc username from the datasource, and the generated query itself doesn't have schema name prefix, resulting in java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the schema is not printed, but you can enable it via

```
OracleTemplates.builder().printSchema().build()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked. (saved me creating a custom OracleTemplates)